# how to check string start in C++

Tags: c++, string

Is there any way in C++ to check whether a string starts with a certain string (smaller than the original) ? Just like  we can do in Java

```
bigString.startswith(smallString);
```

Comment: are you talking C strings or std::String

Comment: i am talking about C++ string.std::string

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
std::string s("Hello world");

if (s.find("Hello") == 0)
{
    std::cout << "String starts with Hello\n";
}
```

Comment: @avakar I agree. I haven't tried the C++11 regular expressions yet, but that would also be a solution, and hopefully more efficient?

Comment: I think regex is a bad choice for such a simple check, see my answer for what I think is an efficient solution for this problem. Or even better Alan Stokes reply with string::compare().

Comment: An efficient solution should be `O(min(bigString.length(), smallString.length()))`

Comment: @sufyansiddique Simple, yes.  Effective, not so very.  If `smallString` is not longer than `bigString`, you only have to compare the first `smallString.size()` characters to know the answer; you don't have to search the entire `bigString` for a `smallString` other than at the initial position.

Comment: As others have commented, this can't be a very efficient idea if the string you're searching is really long and the string you're looking for is really short.  Why iterate through the whole string when you're only interested in the bit at the beginning?

Comment: what if the "Hello" appears at the last or in middle? I think this program is supposed to find any occurence of a particular substring, not meant for "starts with". I think boost string algorithm is good option for this. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878001/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-string-starts-with-a-certain-string-and-convert-a-sub

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee It's the comparison of the result from `find` with zero that does the "starts with" part.

Comment: Why not use: `if (s.rfind("Hello", 0) == 0) {`

Answer (score 70):

You can do this with `string::compare()`, which offers various options for comparing all or parts of two strings. This version compares `smallString` with the appropriate size prefix of `bigString` (and works correctly if `bigString` is shorter than `smallString`):

```
bigString.compare(0, smallString.length(), smallString) == 0
```

I tend to wrap this up in a free function called `startsWith()`, since otherwise it can look a bit mysterious.

UPDATE: [C++20 is adding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) new `starts_with` and `ends_with` functions, so you will finally be able to write just `bigString.starts_with(smallString)`.

Answer (score 32):

The approaches using `string::find()` or `string::substr()` are not optimal since they either make a copy of your string, or search for more than matches at the beginning of the string. It might not be an issue in your case, but if it is you could use the `std::equal` algorithm. Remember to check that the "haystack" is at least as long as the "needle".

```
#include <string>    

using namespace std;

bool startsWith(const string& haystack, const string& needle) {
    return needle.length() <= haystack.length() 
        && equal(needle.begin(), needle.end(), haystack.begin());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct solution, as always, comes from Boost: [`boost::algorithm::starts_with`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/starts_with.html).

Comment: Awful to use boost just to do this simple task.

Comment: @Borzh, surely, you're already using Boost heavily in your projects, why not for this?

Comment: Not everyone uses boost. And to download it, put it in repository just to use starts_with() is a little exaggerating. Maybe you should consider remove "The correct solution, as always...". It is nor "correct" neither "always".

Comment: I'm with avakar. In my eyes this *is* the correct solution. BTW you have to include boost/algorithm/string.hpp

Comment: Agree with Borzh. Not all projects use boost (far from it), so 'always' and 'correct' words do not belong here. To add this monstrosity to a project where STL or simple strcmp would work is madness.

Comment: I second (third?) Borzh and Alex.  This is useful only if you are already using Boost, and even then it's arrogant to call it "_the_ correct solution" – it's not _wrong_, it's not _bad_, but The Boost Way is not the only way.

Answer (score 5):

With C++20 you can use [`std::basic_string::starts_with`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) (or [`std::basic_string_view::starts_with`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with)):

```
#include <string_view>

std::string_view bigString_v("Winter is gone"); // std::string_view avoids the copy in substr below.
std::string_view smallString_v("Winter");
if (bigString_v.starts_with(smallString_v))
{
    std::cout << "Westeros" << bigString_v.substr(smallString_v.size());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To optimize a little bit:

```
if ( smallString.size() <= bigString.size() &&
     strncmp( smallString.c_str(), bigString.c_str(), smallString.length() ) == 0 )
```

Don't forget to `#include <cstring>` or `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

[`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) returns a pointer to the first occurrence of a string within a string.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be:

```
if ( smallString.size() <= bigString.size()
    && std::equals( smallString.begin(), smallString.end(), bigString.end() )
```

(This will also work if one of the two, or both, is a vector.  Or any
other standard container type.)

Comment: -1 1) I cannot find any std::equals. Did you mean std::equal? 2) are you sure with bigString.end() - one would expect bigString.begin()? 3) answer by Kleist posted before seems to get all of this right

Comment: Yes, to both.  It's `std::equal`, and it should be `bigString.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it makes sense to post a raw solution that doesn't use any library functions...

```
// Checks whether `str' starts with `start'
bool startsWith(const std::string& str, const std::string& start) {
    if (&start == &str) return true; // str and start are the same string
    if (start.length() > str.length()) return false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < start.length(); ++i) {
        if (start[i] != str[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Adding a simple `std::tolower` we can make this case insensitive

```
// Checks whether `str' starts with `start' ignoring case
bool startsWithIgnoreCase(const std::string& str, const std::string& start) {
    if (&start == &str) return true; // str and start are the same string
    if (start.length() > str.length()) return false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < start.length(); ++i) {
        if (std::tolower(start[i]) != std::tolower(str[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either create a substring that is the length of your `smallString` variable, and compare the two.  Or do a search for the substring `smallString` and see if it returns index 0

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

You can use string.substr() to see any number of characters from any position, or you could use a string.find() member.