# How to check if <wstring> starts with a certain string using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check string start in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095088/how-to-check-string-start-in-c)

I need to check if wstring begins with a particular string.

```
const wstring str = "Hello World";
wstring temp="Hello ";
```

How I can check `str` begins with `temp` or not?

Comment: sounds a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878001/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-string-starts-with-a-certain-string-and-convert-a-sub

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use wide literals for starters; then it's a breeze:

```
std::wstring const str = L"Hello World";

// one method:
if (str.substr(0, 6) == L"Hello ") { /* yay */ }

// another method, better:
if (str.find(L"Hello ") == 0) { /* hooray */ }
```

Comment: or if you don't want to hard code temp, use str.substr(0, temp.size()) == temp

Comment: Shouldn't the second one be `if (str.find(L"Hello ") == 0) { /* hooray */ }` since the OP wants to know if the string starts with *Hello*

Comment: second one will find also the "Hello" substrings which are not at the beginning ... needs refining

Comment: Thanks to you all for your great help