# How can I use an * wildcard in an if statement?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a simple program that is going to visit a website of the users choosing so I'm using an if statement like:

```
If (url == "http://")
{
    cout << ("Connecting to ") << url;
}
 else
 {
     cout << ("Invalid URL");
}
```

And I'm wondering how I can filter out strings that doesn't start with "http://" or "https://", I'm just starting out so help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `find` and check if it returns 0.

Comment: @NathanOliver but that matches things like `otherstuffhttp://otherstuff`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878001/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-string-starts-with-a-certain-string-and-convert-a-sub

Comment: @Max Not if you check for the return value to be 0, as he suggested.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius fair point

Comment: Thanks! I will look into "find".

Comment: You should not compare strings using == by the way. This will check if the objects are the same, not the content. Use string::compare.

Comment: `std::string` handles `==` just fine, @Aziuth.

Answer (score 1):

A clear, but not particularly fast way, is to use (assuming `url` is a `std::string`)

```
if (url.substr(0, 7) != "http://" && url.substr(0, 8) != "https://"){
    /*I don't start with http:// or https:// */
}
```

Here I'm using `substr` to extract the start of a `std::string` then using the overloaded `!=` operator.

Note that if `url` is shorter than 7 or 8 characters, the behaviour is still well-defined.

You could define `static const char HTTP[] = "http://"` and use `sizeof(HTTP) - 1` &c. so you don't hardcode the lengths, but that might be going a step too far.

For more generality you could venture into the murky world of *regular expressions*. See `std::regex`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible option would be to store the known starting protocols into a vector of strings then use that vector and its fuctions as well as the strings functions to do your tests and if your url is a string object comparison is easy.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main {
    const std::vector<std::string> urlLookUps { "http://", "https://" };

    std::string url( "https://www.home.com" );

    unsigned int size1 = urlLookUps[0].size();
    unsigned int size2 = urlLookUps[1].size();

    if ( url.compare( 0, size1, urlLookUps[0] ) == 0 ||
         url.compare( 0, size2, urlLookUps[1] ) == 0 ) {
         std::cout << url << std::endl;
    } else {
         std::cout << "Invalid Address" << std::endl;
    }                  

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can take this to the next step and turn it into a simple function

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void testUrls( const std::string& url, const std::vector<std::string>& urlLookUps ) {

    std::vector<unsigned int> sizes;

    for ( unsigned int idx = 0; idx < urlLookUps.size(); ++idx ) {
        sizes.push_back( urlLookUps[idx].size() );
    }

    bool foundIt = false;
    for ( unsigned int idx = 0; idx < urlLookUps.size(); ++idx ) {
        if ( url.compare( 0, sizes[idx], urlLookUps[idx] ) == 0 ) {
            foundIt = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    if ( foundIt ) {
        std::cout << url << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid URL" << std::endl;
    }

} // testUrls

int main() {
    const std::vector<std::string> urlLookUps { "http://", "https://" };
    std::string url1( "http://www.home.com" );
    std::string url2( "https://www.home.com" );
    std::string url3( "htt://www.home.com" );

    testUrl( url1, urlLookUps );
    testUrl( url2, urlLookUps );
    testUrl( url3, urlLookUps );

    return 0;
} // main
```

This way you can pass both the URL to the function as well as a container of url protocols that the user may want to populate themselves. This way the function will search through all the strings that are saved into the vector of strings.