# Any way to make parsing & matching of substring faster with boost spirit than default parsing and matching

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to replace an old piece of code which matches if substring is there in end of string with boost spirit. When i benchmark both implementation i see old implementation does it faster.

[**Live On Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85c8ecade213152b)

My questions are

1. Is it wise to expect i would get faster parsing and matching when i replace old code with boost spirit.
2. If (1.) is yes some suggestions on what i am doing wrong or what i shud do try.

**logic explanation:**
if substring is "TRINNDECK"
i need to check the last entry in "SERVERTRINN-11/TRINNDECK-1/TRINNUSER-1" has substring.
all entries have simillar format (STRING-INT/STRING-INT)
so in my example "SERVERMAGNUS-1/MAGNUSDECK-1/TRINNDECK-1" matches but not "SERVERTRINN-11/TRINNDECK-1/TRINNUSER-1"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

bool isSubStrInStr(const std::string subStr, const std::string& str)
{
    auto begin = str.find_last_of('/');
    auto end = str.find_last_of('-');
    if (end != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (begin != std::string::npos)
        {
            if (str.substr((begin + 1), (end - begin - 1)) == subStr)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (str.substr(0, end) == subStr)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool isSubStrInStrSpirit(const std::string& subStr, const std::string& str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    bool const result = boost::spirit::x3::parse(
        str.begin(), str.end(),
        +boost::spirit::x3::alnum % +(boost::spirit::x3::char_('-') >> boost::spirit::x3::int_ >> "/"),
        values
    );

    if (result && values.back() == subStr)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    std::string name = "TRINNDECK";
    std::vector<std::string> infoMaps{
        "SERVERTRINN-11/TRINNDECK-1/TRINNUSER-1",
        "SERVERMAGNUS-1/MAGNUSDECK-1/TRINNDECK-1",
    };

    std::cout << "WITH SPIRIT" << std::endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto& item : infoMaps)
    {
        std::cout << item << "  " << std::boolalpha << isSubStrInStrSpirit(name, item) << std::endl;
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Time taken: " << duration.count() << " microseconds." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "WITHOUT SPIRIT" << std::endl;
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto& item : infoMaps)
    {
        std::cout << item << "  " << std::boolalpha << isSubStrInStr(name, item) << std::endl;
    }
    stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Time taken: " << duration.count() << " microseconds." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the code in the question

Comment: something that takes 6 mircoseconds is not good to make a decision on performance. You need to measure many times with more workload

Comment: note that `high_precision_clock` should not be used for time measurements. Use `std::steady_clock` instead

Comment: Question 1; For this use case: No. Question 2: N/A.

Comment: Parser analyses a string into logical syntactic components. Searching substring in a string is simpler task.

Comment: you might be interested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878001/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-stdstring-starts-with-a-certain-string-and-convert-a. Though in the meantime there is `string_view`. In any case `str.substr(0, end) == subStr` is doing more than you need, because `substr` has to construct a new string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started optimizing, until I bothered to read your original implementation. Here goes my galaxy-brain version:

```
bool isSubStrInStrGalaxybrain(std::string_view expected, std::string_view input) {
    auto last = input.substr(input.find_last_of('/') + 1);
    return expected == last.substr(0, last.find('-'));
}
```

Everybody hates the string/string_view interface, but it is quite powerful if you find the sweet spot.

SPOILER: Take the rest of the original answer with a grain of salt because nothing is going to top this unless you wish to manually SSE4 optimize it (which the compiler might already do anyways):

[image]

## OLD STUFF

I simplified the Spirit parser a bit to be more direct

```
bool isSubStrInStrSpirit(std::string const& expected, std::string const& input) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    std::vector<std::string> values;

    bool result = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), +x3::alnum % +('-' >> x3::int_ >> '/'), values);
    return (result && values.back() == expected);
}
```

Let's look at this.

It does a lot more work than you require. In particular it

- validates the integers and delimiters strictly for the entire input (even though it throws away the result)
- it creates `std::string` entries in the vector for all of the "values" which you donot actually require
- you compile the parser expression each time around.

Besides your benchmarks measure console IO predominantly. Let's use a proper microbenchmark tool with statistical analysis:

```
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Spirit", [](/*nonius::chronometer cm*/) {
    for (auto& item : infoMaps)
        isSubStrInStrSpirit(name, item);
});

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Nospirit", [](/*nonius::chronometer cm*/) {
    for (auto& item : infoMaps)
        isSubStrInStr(name, item);
});
```

Output:

```
clock resolution: mean is 21.2206 ns (20480002 iterations)

benchmarking Spirit
collecting 100 samples, 33 iterations each, in estimated 2.1648 ms
mean: 490.892 ns, lb 479.67 ns, ub 509.147 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 71.4656 ns, lb 49.6218 ns, ub 98.7286 ns, ci 0.95
found 21 outliers among 100 samples (21%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking Nospirit
collecting 100 samples, 315 iterations each, in estimated 2.1105 ms
mean: 60.2737 ns, lb 59.6758 ns, ub 61.197 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 3.69908 ns, lb 2.68804 ns, ub 5.1282 ns, ci 0.95
found 21 outliers among 100 samples (21%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

This confirms the expected slowness.

### Fixing/Improving

1. #### Avoid recompiling parser expression

   Let's get the rule compilation out of the hot-path:

   ```
   namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
   static const inline auto rule = +x3::alnum % +('-' >> x3::int_ >> '/');

   bool isSubStrInStrSehe(std::string const& expected, std::string const& input) {
       std::vector<std::string> values;
       bool result = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), rule, values);
       return (result && values.back() == expected);
   }
   ```

   [image]

   Minimal change :) Compilers do optimize X3 neatly
2. #### Avoid string construction

   ```
   bool isSubStrInStrSehe(std::string_view expected, std::string_view input) {
       std::vector<boost::iterator_range<char const*> > values;
       bool result = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), rule, values);
       return (result && values.back() == expected);
   }
   ```

   That's very simple, and makes the function interface a lot more flexible to boot. Now we're seeing the difference! [image]
3. #### Avoid vector construction

   You only need the last value. Let's cut the vector, and use a semantic action to remember the last matched value:

   ```
   static const inline auto token     = x3::raw[+x3::alnum];
   static const inline auto trailer = '-' >> x3::int_ >> '/';

   bool isSubStrInStrSehe(std::string_view expected, std::string_view input) {
       boost::iterator_range<char const*> last;
       auto assign = [&last](auto& ctx) { last = _attr(ctx); };

       bool result = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), token[assign] % +trailer);

       return (result && last == expected);
   }
   ```

   If you're like me, the result is disappointing [image]

Comment: I forgot to include the combined listing because of the change of plan at the end. Here it is in case anyone misses something http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b81abb5e5219ae5f

Comment: wow. thanks for all the effort u've put in explaining. This is amazing.