# How to remove a particular substring from a string?

Tags: c++, string, substring

In my C++ program, I have the string

```
string s = "/usr/file.gz";
```

Here, how to make the script to check for `.gz` extention (whatever the file name is) and split it like `"/usr/file"`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/874160/276994

Comment: @Vlad you should close vote, instead of linking

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: well, it's not a full duplicate: the said question only checks for the ending, but doesn't remove it. I'm vague about it.

Comment: "the script"? do you want an answer in some scripting language?

Comment: There's like hundreds of different ways you can do this. Have you really not tried/found anything? Like here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
// Check if the last three characters match the ext.
const std::string ext(".gz");
if ( s != ext &&
     s.size() > ext.size() &&
     s.substr(s.size() - ext.size()) == ".gz" )
{
   // if so then strip them off
   s = s.substr(0, s.size() - ext.size());
}
```

Comment: substr() always creates new object. It's not sounds well by performance reasons.

Comment: @Alexander: True, but there was no mention of performance considerations in the question.

Comment: With very similar code, I managed to wipe 3 complete PCs(*). You probably want `s.size() > 3`, as `".gz"` is a hidden file and should not be stripped to `""`. ( * I stripped too much, added `*` and then did a `rm -rf /*` )

Comment: @MSalters: An impressive achievement! Tell me you *didn't* run it as root? :) I only really intended this as a simple example for the OP but I think your point is very important in context and I've changed accordingly. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: This code looks more complicated than necessary. Doesn't C++ have an `ends_with` method like in Java or Python? And what is the point of `s != ext`? The code would work equally well without that comparison.

Answer (score 64):

You can use [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) for removing symbols:

```
str.erase(start_position_to_erase, number_of_symbols);
```

And you can use [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the starting position:

```
start_position_to_erase = str.find("smth-to-delete");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to use C++11, you can use `#include <regex>` or if you're stuck with C++03 you can use Boost.Regex (or PCRE) to form a proper regular expression to break out the parts of a filename you want. Another approach is to use Boost.Filesystem for parsing paths properly.

Comment: regex should be an overkill for such a simple task

Answer (score 2):

Or shorter version of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44861722/117220) (C++11)

```cpp
std::string stripExtension(const std::string &filePath) {
    return {filePath, 0, filePath.rfind('.')};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17, you can use the built-in [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library to treat file paths, which is derived from the [BOOST filesystem library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). Note that the operator `/` has been overloaded to concatenate `std::filesystem::path`s.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

std::string stripExtension(const std::string &path_str) {
  std::filesystem::path p{path_str};
  if (p.extension() == ".gz") {
    return p.parent_path() / p.stem();
  }
  return {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void stripExtension(std::string &path)
{
    int dot = path.rfind(".gz");
    if (dot != std::string::npos)
    {
        path.resize(dot);
    }
}
```