# How to remove a prefix or a suffix from a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, prefix, suffix

Some others have asked about

- [how to remove an arbitrary substring from a string in c++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532384/how-to-remove-a-particular-substring-from-a-string)
- [how to check whether a string ends with a given prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878001/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-stdstring-starts-with-a-certain-string-and-convert-a)
- [how to check whether a string ends with a given suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-out-if-string-ends-with-another-string-in-c/42844629)

However, it has not yet been asked how to remove a prefix or a suffix from a string in c++. Assuming that we know that a given string starts with a specific prefix/suffix, some specialized methods may be used.

So: Given the following, how do we remove the prefix and suffix?

```cpp
  std::string prefix = "prefix.";
  std::string suffix = ".suffix";
  std::string full_string = "prefix.content.suffix";
  std::string just_the_middle = ???;
```

Comment: when you know how to remove an arbitrary substring, you also know how to remove a pre/suffix, no?

Comment: Yes, it is true that techniques for removing arbitrary substrings will work to remove a prefix/suffix. However, given techniques for removing a prefix/suffix, those techniques will not necessarily work to remove an arbitrary substring. My intention here was to collect techniques for removing a prefix/suffix specifically, which might involve cleaner / clearer code than techniques that are applicable to arbitrary substrings.

Comment: sorry, but they dont (involve much cleaner / clearer code). The accepted answer on "How to remove arbitrarys?" is specifically about removing a suffix (and the questions too, just the title is more general)

Comment: The post you linked actually does a better job for removing the suffix than your answer on this post.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know ahead of time that `full_string` starts/ends with prefix/suffix, one can use `std::string::substr`:

```cpp
  std::string prefix = "prefix.";
  std::string suffix = ".suffix";
  std::string full_string = "prefix.content.suffix";
  
  // prefix removal
  std::string result1 = full_string.substr(prefix.length());
  
  // suffix removal
  std::string result2 = full_string.substr(0, full_string.length() - suffix.length());
```

Comment: It is bad suggestion because you don't remove "prefix." or ".suffix", you remove 7 arbitrary characters.