# Is it safe to call std::equal on potentially shorter input if I know there will be difference detected within size of input

Tags: c++, stl

While doing some nw programming I stumbled upon the following dilemma:

Im doing something like:

```
static const string my_ip_prefix = "111.222.233";

//going through list of IPs where one might have prefix my_ip_prefix

if (equal(my_ip_prefix .begin(), my_ip_prefix .end(), ip_list[i].begin())))
{
//
}
```

If I know IPs from `ip_list` can be shorter than my_ip_prefix, but that in that case they differ from `my_ip_prefix` on at least one position in them is it safe to call equal? 
Example : is it safe to call it with ip `"10.20.30.4"`

Aka does standard mandates sequential checks starting from front and `break;` in `std::equal`?

It might seem obvious that A is yes, but maybe ISO ppl wanted to give option implementations to parallelize...

Comment: Why not use `ip_list[i].compare(0, my_ip_prefix.length(), my_ip_prefix)`?

Comment: Please note that a real IPv4 address never has `.333.` in it, so you could replace you comparison with `false`.

Comment: ups, was just trying to give example that doesnt use real data :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++03 `std::equal()` requires the second sequence to be at least as long as the first one.

In C++14 there is another overload of [`std::equal()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) that takes two iterators for the second sequence.

---

You should convert the IP addresses into `uint32_t` and compare those instead, e.g.:

```
auto ip_prefix = ::inet_addr("111.222.233.0");
auto ip_mask = ::inet_addr("255.255.255.0");

bool compare(in_addr_t a, in_addr_t b, in_addr_t mask) {
    return (a & mask) == (b & mask);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << compare(ip_prefix, ::inet_addr("1.1.1.1"), ip_mask) << '\n';
    std::cout << compare(ip_prefix, ::inet_addr("111.222.233.3"), ip_mask) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: ...but requires them to be the same distance apart as the input iterators. And it [seems](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) to be C++14

Comment: @Chowlett You are right, did not expect C++14 in there yet )

Comment: advice about uint32_t is wrong since im doing is_prefix, other than that good A, +1

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Look at the example I provided.

Comment: I just used boost::starts_with

Answer (score 5):

If we look at the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) entry for [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) it says:

> [...]where last2 denotes first2 + (last1 - first1)

which means that `ip_list[i]` will need to be at least as long. This corresponds with the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) which in section `25.2.11` *Equal* says:

```
template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
  bool equal(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
             InputIterator2 first2);
```

> Returns: true if for every iterator i in the range [first1,last1) the following corresponding conditions hold: *i == *(first2 + (i - first1)), [...]

In [C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) you have a version of that takes a end iterator for the second input, same section as *C++11*:

```
template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
  bool equal(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
             InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2);
```

and it says:

> If last1 - first1 != last2 - first2, return false. [...]

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no.  There is no requirement that the
element comparisons be done in order.  But since you're using
`std::string`, which have random access iterators (and
a `size()` function), it's trivial to check beforehand that the
length is enough:

```
if ( ip_list[i].size() >= my_ip_prefix
        && std::equal( my_ip_prefix.begin(), my_ip_prefix.end(), ip_list[i].begin() ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: i know but that makes my if ugly as hell since it is not only condition... like mentioned in prev comment I just used boost::starts_with