# How do check if the last substring is a value and remove it if so

Tags: c++

I need to remove "Time" from some strings, if it is present as the last substring. The solution needs to work for these cases:

```
    "AmpliTime"               =>   "Ampli"
    "IsoTimeTime"             =>   "IsoTime"
    "SometypeTimeAndThenTime" =>   "SometypeTimeAndThen"
    "SometypeTimeAndThenTimeAbc" =>   "SometypeTimeAndThenTimeAbc"
```

I have tried something like this but it runs into problems if the word Time appears somewhere else besides the end.

```
long start = s.find("Time");
if (start > 0)
{
    printf("%d\n", start);
    s.erase(start, 5);
}
printf("%d\n", start);
```

Comment: why not separate last 5 elements and check them instead of using find function like (puesdocode) vector<string> str.append(s.size()-5, s.size()) and then check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rfind` is potentially inefficient since in the case where the string *doesn't* end with `Time` it will keep searching the string.

`compare`, however, looks at exactly the part of the string you're interested in:

```
if (s.size() >= 4 && s.compare(s.size()-4, 4, "Time") == 0) {
    s.resize(s.size() - 4);
}
```

As you see, I've used the number `4` four times in the code. Dubious style, but it gets the job done. I've decided that for a case with a fixed string so short, this is clearer than putting the length in a variable, but YMMV.

Comment: There are a whole bunch more ways of testing string ending at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-if-string-endswith-another-string-in-c but I haven't marked this a dupe because this question also asks about the erase part. Depending how you do the test, you might have some information significant to the erase (like `start` would be the questioner's attempt at the problem, if it was correct in all cases!). And also because in this question you might want to avoid the overhead of creating `string("Time")`.