# Translate the code from Python to C++

Tags: python, c++

Now when I understand how the code works, I would like to translate it to C++.

The original Python code:

```
def recv_all_until(s, crlf):
    data = ""
    while data[-len(crlf):] != crlf:
        data += s.recv(1)
    return data
```

Here's what I tried:

```
std::string recv_all_until(int socket, std::string crlf)
{
    std::string data = "";
    char buffer[1];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1);


    while(data.substr(data.length()-2, data.length()) != crlf)
    {
        if ((recv(socket, buffer, 1, 0)) == 0)
        {
            if (errno != 0)
            {
                close(socket);
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        data = data + std::string(buffer);
        memset(buffer, 0, 1);
    }

    return data;
}
```

But it shows:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
```

I understand that the problem is inside the `while` loop since at first the data string is empty. So how to improve this to make it work the same as it works in Python? Thank you.

Comment: FYI, Python strings have the method `endswith` which makes your while loop intention much clearer: `while not data.endswith(crlf)`. With that in mind, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2072890/4859885) provides a very elegant solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we first change your Python code a bit:

```
def recv_all_until(s, crlf):
    data = ""
    while not data.endswith(crlf):
        data += s.recv(1)
    return data
```

What we need to do in C++ becomes much clearer:

```
bool ends_with(const std::string& str, const std::string& suffix)
{
    return str.size() >= suffix.size() &&
        std::equal(suffix.rbegin(), suffix.rend(), str.rbegin());
}

std::string recv_all_until(int socket, const std::string& crlf)
{
    std::string data = "";
    char buffer[1];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1);

    while (!ends_with(data, crlf))
    {
        if ((recv(socket, buffer, 1, 0)) == 0)
        {
            if (errno != 0)
            {
                close(socket);
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        data = data + std::string(buffer);
        memset(buffer, 0, 1);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the problem in the first iteration of your `while` loop:

Since the `data` is an empty `string`, `data.length()` is equal to `0`, and thus you're calling `data.substr(-2, 0)`.

To fix this, you need to add a check for the line length to the `while` statement.

Also, there's a method of finding such mistakes faster than writing a stackoverflow question about it. Consider reading [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) article.