# C read conf file

Tags: c, file

Hello i have a problem when i try to read conf file (line by line)

this is my code :

```
bool EndWith(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
    bool rv = 0;
    if (haystack && needle)
    {
        size_t needle_size = strlen(needle);
        const char* act = haystack;
        while (NULL != (act = strstr(act, needle)))
        {
            if (*(act + needle_size) == '\0')
            {
                rv = 1;
                break;
            }
            act += needle_size;
        }
    }

    return rv;
}
    FILE *file2 = fopen ("config.conf", "r");
    const size_t line_size = 300;
    char* line = malloc(line_size);
    while (fgets(line, line_size, file2) != NULL)  {
        puts(line);

        if(EndWith(line, "toto")) {
            puts("yes");
        }
    }
```

and my conf file :

```
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072 toto
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100 toto
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0 toto
```

My code return 2 "Yes" but if my conf file, if i add a line feed in first line i read my 3 lines and my code return 3 "Yes"
Why ?

i want to return 3 "Yes" without need to add a line feed in line0 of my conf file

bug retrurn :

```
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072 toto

yes
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100 toto

yes
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0 toto
```

correct return (with add a line feed)

```
yes
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072 toto

yes
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100 toto

yes
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0 toto
```

---

i tested solution Filip Kočica (thanks for your help) but i have same problem :

the code:

```
bool EndWith(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
    if (haystack == NULL || needle == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    const char* p;
    if ((p = strstr(haystack, needle)) != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(p, haystack + strlen(haystack) - strlen(needle)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *file2 = fopen ("config.conf", "r");
        const size_t line_size = 300;
        char* line = malloc(line_size);
        while (fgets(line, line_size, file2) != NULL)  {
            puts(line);

            if (EndWith(line, "za"))
            {
                puts("it does.");
            }

        }



        return 0;
}
```

my file config.conf :

```
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072 za
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 1001 za
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 01 za
```

Comment: What is a spaceline?

Comment: I think he is talking about an empty line.

Comment: Does your file finishing by an `\n` ? (Without, the last line is not finishing by `\n` and so will no print `yes`)

Comment: i edit my message, it's not "space line" but "a line feed", sorry

Comment: It appears that the last line of your file doesn't have a linefeed at the end.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this statement: `if (!strcmp(p, haystack + strlen(haystack) - strlen(needle)))` will probably fail on every line that ends with '\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1]

It return's 2 becouse last row doesn't end with new line character `\n`.

Everytime you call getline it gives you one line from file (If there is another line).
There is no need for checking if this line really end's with `NL` character.
Just count how many times getline didn't return `EOF`.

Get `puts` out of condition

```
while (fgets(line, line_size, file2) != NULL)
{
    puts(line);
    puts("yes");

    if(EndWith(line, /*special strings*/ ))
    {

    }
}
```

2]

```
bool EndWith(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
    if (haystack == NULL || needle == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    const char* p;
    if ((p = strstr(haystack, needle)) != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(p, haystack + strlen(haystack) - strlen(needle) - 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *file2 = fopen ("config.conf", "r");
        const size_t line_size = 300;
        char* line = malloc(line_size);
        while (fgets(line, line_size, file2) != NULL)  {
            if (EndWith(line, "za"))
            {
                puts("it does.");
            }

            puts(line);
        }



        return 0;
}
```

config file:

```
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072 za
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 1001 za
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 01 za
```

OUTPUT:

```
it does.
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072 za

it does.
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 1001 za

it does.
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 01 za
```

Comment: i want to check if my line end with special strings, i inspired by this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-if-string-ends-with-another-string-in-c
but yes i think i have problem with \n and eof

Comment: Ok so check for _special strings_, but not for `\n` :-)

Comment: Yes, i edit my message, i want to check if my line end with "toto"

Comment: I've did it for you, it should work. Just replace function `EndWith`.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i have same problem, i add your code in new message

Comment: Np, glad it helped. But code i posted work's so you should mark it as answered :-)

Comment: @user7454761 NOW it finally work's as you want (updated answer), i didnt notice what you exactly want to do. :-)