# check if a vector contains a substring of another vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I have file names and I need to check if these files end with any extension of the vector extensions; I would like to use some of the algorithms that are in the library  instead of how I have done it, is there any way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::string tail(const std::string &st, const size_t len)
{
    if (len >= st.size())
        return st;
    return st.substr(st.size() - len);
}

std::vector<std::string> filtered_files(const std::vector<std::string>& files, const std::vector<std::string>& extensions) {

    std::vector<std::string> re;
    for(const std::string f : files) {
        for(const std::string ex : extensions) {
            if(ex == tail(f,ex.size())) {
                re.push_back(std::move(f));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return re;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::vector<std::string> v{"main.cpp","main.c","main.py"};
    std::vector<std::string> re = filtered_files(v,{".c",".cpp"});
    for(const std::string s  :re) {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: That's kind of an open-ended question. Of course you can. As a first step, check out the algorithms and see if you reimplemented any of them. Then, replace your implementation with that from the standard library.

Comment: I think the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874160/416574) on this question will be very helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-out-if-string-ends-with-another-string-in-c  it is making use of the string::compare function and uses an index computation to calculate the end of the string for comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) standard algorithm in place of the inner loop.  You can use the [`std::string::compare()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) method to perform substring comparisons without having to actually allocate new `std::string` objects, as your loops and `tail()` function currently do.  The only string allocations you need are for the strings pushed into `re` (and even that allocation can be avoided if you return a `std::vector<std::string*>` of pointers that point to the strings in te `files` vector).

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> filtered_files(const std::vector<std::string>& files, const std::vector<std::string>& extensions)
{
    std::vector<std::string> re;

    for(const std::string &f : files)
    {
        if (std::find_if(extensions.begin(), extensions.end(),
            [&](const std::string &ex){
                return (f.size() >= ex.size()) && (f.compare(f.size()-ex.size(), ex.size(), ex) == 0);
            }
        ) != extensions.end())
        {
            re.push_back(f);
        }
    }

    return re;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/hXGlDk)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many ways of solving this, personally, this is the way I've achieved it before

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"main.cpp","main.c","main.py"};
    std::vector<std::string> ext{".cpp", ".c"};
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    for (auto& s : v) {
        auto pos = s.find_last_of('.');            
        if (pos != s.npos) {
            char* str = &s[pos];
            if (std::any_of(ext.begin(), ext.end(), 
                            [str](const string& a) { return str ==  a; })) {
                res.push_back(s);
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto& r : res)
        cout << r << endl;

    return 0;
}
```