# RapidJSON - using wildcards to iterate through complex JSON structures with different member names

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have a complex JSON to load into a data structure in C++11 and I got high recommendations about RapidJSON. I need to iterate over a complex JSON and looked around for answers on how to do it. The best answer I found was in [this thread](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues/1343).

However, there's a small glitch in matching this solution to mine, I have members in the JSON that have different names but identical content:

```
"responsibilities": {
  "starters_reciepe": {
    "name": "bok choi salad",
    "type": "veggie",
    "ingredients": {
      "leafyIng": "bok choi",
      "proteinIng": "tofu",
      "seasoning": [
        {
          "2 tsp": "salt",
          "1 tsp": "turmric"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "mainCourse_reciepe": {
    "name": "pad tai",
    "type": "yum yum",
    "ingredients": {
      "leafyIng": "chard",
      "proteinIng": "soylent green"
      "seasoning": [
        {
          "2 tsp": "black pepper",
          "1 tsp": "tears of the angels"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

}

Basically, I need to go over the content of the ingredients, but I can't get over the fact that starters_reciepe is not like mainCourse_reciepe.

**EDITED:**
Here's my code:

```
Document d;

ifstream in("TestingJSON.json", ios::binary);
if (!in)
    throw runtime_error("Failed to open file");

istreambuf_iterator<char> head(in);
istreambuf_iterator<char> tail;
string data(head, tail);

d.Parse(data.c_str());

const Value& prog = d["responsibilities"];
for (Value::ConstValueIterator p = prog.Begin(); p != prog.End(); ++p) {
cout << (*p)["iUniqueID"].GetString()<<endl;
    const Value& inFiles = (*p)["inFiles"];
    for (Value::ConstValueIterator inFile = inFiles.Begin(); inFile != prog.End(); ++inFile) {
        cout << (*inFile)["sFileType"].GetString() << endl;
        cout << (*inFile)["pos"]["x1"].GetInt() << endl;
    }
}
```

Can I use wildcards and write *_reciepe?

I could find anything on RapidJSON and wildcards. Is this even a possibility?

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid. Check with an online linter e.g. https://jsonlint.com/. And, the code you posted is a copy of the [link](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues/1343#issuecomment-412591805) you posted above. It has nothing to do with the JSON you posted. You need to update the correct JSON with your correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always validate your raw JSON with linters (e.g. https://jsonlint.com/). This JSON in your question is not valid. You need to fix that.

The `"responsibilites"` object in your JSON contains recipes only. I'm not sure why you need to compare it with `*_recipe`. But, given the example below, you may easily implement that comparison if needed. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-out-if-string-ends-with-another-string-in-c) might be helpful in this regard.

---

You can use C++11's range-based for loop for these iterations. Just take care of the correct type you want to use/manipulate according to your use-case. If in doubt, consult rapidjson's [tutorial](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html) and documentation.

Here's an example with raw literal string as JSON input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto data = R"json(
    {
      "responsibilities": {
          "starters_recipe": {
              "name": "bok choi salad",
              "type": "veggie",
              "ingredients": {
                  "leafyIng": "bok choi",
                  "proteinIng": "tofu",
                  "seasoning": [{
                      "2 tsp": "salt",
                      "1 tsp": "turmric"
                  }]
              }
          },
          "mainCourse_recipe": {
              "name": "pad tai",
              "type": "yum yum",
              "ingredients": {
                  "leafyIng": "chard",
                  "proteinIng": "soylent green",
                  "seasoning": [{
                      "2 tsp": "black pepper",
                      "1 tsp": "tears of the angels"
                  }]
              }
          }
      }
    }
    )json";

    rapidjson::Document doc;
    doc.Parse( data );

    const auto& courses = doc["responsibilities"].GetObject();
    for ( const auto& course : courses )
    {
        const auto& course_name = course.name.GetString();
        const auto& recipe      = courses[course_name].GetObject();
        const auto& recipe_name = recipe["name"].GetString();
        const auto& ingredients = recipe["ingredients"].GetObject();
        const auto& leafyIng    = ingredients["leafyIng"].GetString();
        const auto& proteinIng  = ingredients["proteinIng"].GetString();
        const auto& seasoning   = ingredients["seasoning"].GetArray()[0].GetObject();

        std::cout << "Course: " << course_name << '\n'
                  << "Recipe: " << recipe_name << '\n'
                  << "Ingredients:\n"
                  << "- Leaf     : " << leafyIng << '\n'
                  << "- Protein  : " << proteinIng << '\n'
                  << "- Seasoning:\n";

        for ( const auto& s : seasoning )
        {
            const auto& k = s.name.GetString();
            const auto& v = s.value.GetString();
            std::cout << "  - " << k << ", " << v << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Course: starters_recipe
Recipe: bok choi salad
Ingredients:
- Leaf     : bok choi
- Protein  : tofu
- Seasoning:
  - 2 tsp, salt
  - 1 tsp, turmric

Course: mainCourse_recipe
Recipe: pad tai
Ingredients:
- Leaf     : chard
- Protein  : soylent green
- Seasoning:
  - 2 tsp, black pepper
  - 1 tsp, tears of the angels
```

---

The `"seasoning"` array contains only one object that's why this line refers to the 0th index:

```
const auto& seasoning = ingredients["seasoning"].GetArray()[0].GetObject();
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
```

I guess that you intended to have an array of objects, not an array with a single object.

This:

```
"seasoning": [   
     { "2 tsp": "black pepper" },
     {  "1 tsp": "tears of the angels" }
]
```

and, not this:

```
"seasoning": [{    
      "2 tsp": "black pepper",
      "1 tsp": "tears of the angels"
}]
```

You have to manipulate this accordingly in code also.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check only if a string ends with a known value this is quite simple to do directly comparing it without wildcards libraries:

```
auto& obj = doc["responsibilities"];
std::string suffix = "_reciepe";
for (auto p = obj.MemberBegin(); p != obj.MemberEnd(); ++p) {
    auto& member_name = p->name;
    if (member_name.GetStringLength() >= suffix.length()) {
        if (memcmp(member_name.GetString() + member_name.GetStringLength() - suffix.length(), suffix.c_str(), suffix.length()) == 0) {
            // Process matching node
            std::cout << p->value["name"].GetString() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to match against more complex patterns then you can use [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match#Example)

Comment: That looks great, but I tried to run it and got: Assertion failed: IsObject(), file c:\testingcode\rapidjson\document.h, line 1285 TestingCode.exe (process 90364) exited with code 3

I edited the original post and added my code.